# generic constraint to restrict collection to have same type of derived objects

Tags: c#, generics, generic-constraints

I want to restrict Collection to have have only same type of class  using generic.

```
public class InvoiceLine<T> where T : TransactionLine ,new() 
{

    private readonly IList<TransactionLine> _transactionLines = new List<TransactionLine>();
    public virtual IReadOnlyCollection<TransactionLine> TransactionLines => new ReadOnlyCollection<TransactionLine>(_transactionLines);

    public virtual void AddTransactionLine(TransactionLine transactionLine)
    {
        transactionLine.ThrowIfNull(nameof(transactionLine), "can't be null");
        _transactionLines.Add(transactionLine);
    }

    protected TransactionLine()
    {
        //doing some validation related stuff here.
    }

}

public abstract class TransactionLine : BaseEntity, IPeopleSoftCostCode, ICustomerAccountNumber
{
    public virtual InvoiceLine<TransactionLine> InvoiceLine { get; set; }
}

public class PermTransactionLine : TransactionLine
{

    public Perm Perm { get; set; }
}

 public class TempTransactionLine : TransactionLine
{
    public Temp Temp { get; set; }
}
```

I want to have `InvoiceLine.TransactionLines`  to contain same type of `TransactionLine`s not `PermTransactionLine` and `TempTransactionLine` together
 at same time. `TransactionLine` must be abstract - dont want to create object directly.

I am trying to add `new()` constaint but doesn't work it says:

> TransactionLine must have public parameterless constructor.

I am then using InvoiceLine to add it to invoice - intially I have all types of transactionlines together as part of billing run and then I will create invoices for specific transaction type.

any idea , How I can achieve this ?

Comment: where do you intend to use `T`? I don't see the point of using a generic variable if you want to restrict it to only accept the type `TransactionLine`

Comment: I am then using InvoiceLine<TransactionLine> to add it to invoice - intially I have all types of transactionlines together as part of billing run and then I will create invoices for specific transaction type.

Answer (score 0):

You may define

```
public class PermInvoiceLine : InvoiceLine<PermTransactionLine> { }
public class TempInvoiceLine : InvoiceLine<TempTransactionLine> { }
```

and use appropriate `XXXInvoiceLine` for each `XXXTransactionLine`.

There is no point defining `T : new()` constraint in this particular case.

Comment: issue is my billing logic is based on InvoiceLine<TransactionLine> which will have all type only I want compile type check that when I add this collection in invoice it must have same type of transactions

Comment: also worth noting InvoiceLine<TransactionLine> is mapped via nhibernate discriminator so really can't change structure.